# Custom CSRF token in .NET

Tags: .net, csrf, web-services

I'm looking for recommendations on how to create a custom anti-CSRF token in my .NET application. We use ViewState for most of the app but we would like to implement the custom token protection in a few calls to .asmx web services.

How do I create a secure custom token in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating one, I'd recommend using one of the freely available, time-tested, quality, existing ones.

For example: http://anticsrf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

First of all ViewState isn't just some magic wand that stops CSRF,  if anything ViewState is the source of more attacks than it prevents.   ViewState will [prevent CSRF if you have ViewStateUserKey enabled](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Viewstate_.28ASP.NET.29). (Is this enabled on your system???)

You can read the [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and choose a method that works best for your.  The most common method is a [random token included with every request](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the info but I think you may have misunderstood my question. I have decided to use a random token already, I'm just looking for recommendations on how to generate the custom token in .NET

Comment: @Trynity then you should have asked, "How do I generate a secure random number in .net".